# Large-scale MPI merge

Tags: merge, parallel-processing, mpi

In an MPI application, I generated a (huge) number of files to campaign storage (GPFS or Lustre). Each file consists of a sequence of tuples `(timestamp, data)`, already sorted by timestamp.

I'm looking for the most efficient possible way to merge all those files to a single sorted log, ideally scalable and in parallel.

The naive approach, which is keeping one file descriptor per file and sequentially build the merged file does not scale well. First, the system file descriptor limit is reached quite fast – it is capped at 100,000 files (that is, ~100.000 cores), when the goal is to scale the application to 1.000.000+ cores (on [Sequoia](https://computation.llnl.gov/computers/sequoia)).

The intermediate approach I can think of would be to create a merge tree. That is, merge sub-groups of files to a bigger one, then iterate over those until we get a completely sorted file.

Do you know of any better-performing approach to that problem, or publications that would set the state of the art for that problem?

Thanks.

Comment: You should consider merging the data during generation instead of post-mortem. Parallel file systems are not exactly friends with hundresd of thousands of files in any case.

Comment: Thanks @Zulan. Problem is, PFS are even less friends of parallel appends to the same file (for  distributed logs). The performance I get in that case is simply catastrophic due to huge lock contention and the way Lustre or GPFS handle appends.

Comment: If you are using POSIX, yes. But you can and should use some parallel I/O library / framework / middleware. I'm not an expert on that, but I'm sure LLNL has someone who can give you specific recommendations for the local file system.

Comment: i do not think you need to have all files open at the same time : for all your files, you can open/read a bunch of records/close and start merging directly to the output file. when the "bunch of records" is exhausted, then re-open the file, seek and read a new bunch of records, close and so on until all gets merged.
you can parallelize that by using a merge tree : you can either get a bunch of records directly from the files, or a partially merged of records from an other task.